# Executing python in 64 bit mode on Mac OS X 10.10

Tags: python, macos, 64-bit

I'm trying to execute python on 64 bit mode.

From this post: [How to force using 64 bit python on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207324/how-to-force-using-64-bit-python-on-mac-os-x), I checked that the python has both 32/64 bit binary.

```
> lipo -info `which python`
> Architectures in the fat file: /usr/bin/python are: x86_64 i386
```

However, when I tried to use python both in 32 and 64 bit mode, I get always 32bit implementation, I used the hints in [How do I force Python to be 32-bit on Snow Leopard and other 32-bit/64-bit questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088569/how-do-i-force-python-to-be-32-bit-on-snow-leopard-and-other-32-bit-64-bit-quest)

```
> defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Prefer-32-Bit -bool no
> python -c 'import sys; print sys.maxint'
> arch -i386 python -c 'import sys; print sys.maxint'

> defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Prefer-32-Bit -bool yes
> python -c 'import sys; print sys.maxint'
> arch -x86_64 python -c 'import sys; print sys.maxint'

2147483647
2147483647
2147483647
2147483647
```

What might be wrong? I use Mac OS X 10.10.2.

Comment: One alternative is to use the python version brought by homebrew
* It is more up to date
* It works in 64 bits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Jeff's comment, I installed python from `brew`.

```
> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/bin/python -c 'import sys; print sys.maxint'
9223372036854775807
```

Now, it works fine at least with brew's python.