# The installation directory of pip

Tags: python, macos, pip

On Mac OS X, I've had the packages directory of `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`. However, after installing 64 bit Python from brew ([Executing python in 64 bit mode on Mac OS X 10.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29185944/executing-python-in-64-bit-mode-on-mac-os-x-10-10)), I find that `pip install` installs the package into a new `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`  directory.

How can I control the target directory where the `pip` command installs the packages? I can I make the default target directory for `pip` from one to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, at least by calling the right `pip`. Thus, if you install `pip` through the base OS X Python (`/usr/bin/easy_install pip`, I would guess), then *this* pip (`/usr/bin/pip`, I would guess) will install new packages in the base OS X Python library (`/Library/Python/…`).

Now, you would normally not want to do this, and instead *completely* move to whatever Python you want to use (that would be brew's, in your case). In fact, this makes things simpler, since you have a single version of Python to care about, where you can put all the packages you need.

Answer (score 0):

I simply revert back to original with reinstallation of `pip` with `sudo easy_install pip`. This installs `/usr/local/bin/pip`.

I also checked that the `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/bin/pip` is symbolically linked to (overwritten) `/usr/local/bin/pip`.

I aliased a command `alias pip64='/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/bin/pip'` so that the brew's python package installation is executed with `pip64` whereas the normal case is with `pip`.

Comment: Where `sudo easy_install pip` installs actually *depends on your path* settings (for instance, on my machine, it installs pip for MacPorts, not in `/usr/local/bin/`). This is why I used explicit paths in my answer. :)