# How to force Python into 64bit mode

Tags: python-3.x, macos, tensorflow

I am having a strange error on my MacBook Air (M1, 2020) where python3.8 is being installed as a 64 bit binary from homebrew `brew install python@3.8` and yet, is being run in 32 bit mode, thus causing errors when trying to download packages.

Here is what I have tried:

1. Reinstalling and confirming that the executable is running in 32 bit

```sh
$ brew reinstall python@3.8 #installs to /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3
$ python3.8 -c 'import sys;print("%x" % sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize > 2**64)'
> 7fffffffffffffff False
```

2. Looking at architecture of binary

```sh
$ file /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3
> /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64
```

From the above output, one can see that the executable is in fact 64-bit despite being run in 32 bit mode.

3. Additional installation of Rosetta 2, a mac update supposedly to fix this problem

```
$ /usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
```

4. Attempt to force binary in 64 bit arch

```
$ arch -x86_64 /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3
> arch: posix_spawnp: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3: Bad CPU type in executable
```

Here is relevant, but sadly unhelpful for my needs, stack overflow tickets:

[How to force using 64 bit python on Mac-os-X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207324/how-to-force-using-64-bit-python-on-mac-os-x) 
[Installation issue with Tensorflow Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720833/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-tensorflow) 
[How to determine if python is in 32 or 64 bit mode mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit) 
[Bad CPU type in executable Mac Rosetta 2 Instructions](https://linuxpip.org/fix-bad-cpu-type-in-executable/#Install_Rosetta_2)

Any ideas would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: Wait, your output implies to me that the exectuable is running in 64bit...

Comment: Good catch! I think I entered in the wrong command... 2\*\*64 instead of 2\*\*32, I will look into this further because after this confirmation it seems like the issue is due to the specific package or another unrelated issue. I will close this, but thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had an error in my command:

`python3.8 -c 'import sys;print("%x" % sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize > 2**64)'`

should be:

`python3.8 -c 'import sys;print("%x" % sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize > 2**32)'`

Which returns true when you're running python in 64 bit mode.

This specific problem is likely something else, and as such I am closing this question.